# My script not running on start up (linux-lite)

Tags: linux, init-script

I have script and I want it to run when my system reboot.
I put the script in `/etc/init.d/superscript`

and add script to end of the `rc.local`

```
bash /etc/init.d/superscript
# i also test this
source /etc/init.d/superscript
```

but nothing happened when I rebooted the system.
The file script have `755` perm.

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi Arash, can you please try using "bash /etc/init.d/superscript >>/tmp/superscript.log 2>&1" in your rc.local and check the logfile /tmp/superscript.log after boot. Also the content of your superscript might help for seeing what goes wrong :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep the script in `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/superscript` and make `symlink` with `/etc/init.d/superscript`.

`/etc/rc.d/rcX.d` directory contain scripts which are execute at boot time or at runlevel changing.

- If script name start with S it means script start at boot time.
- If script name start with K it means script stop/kill at boot time.

If you want to start superscript in `runlevel 3` then create link with S.